# Use jQuery to delete a duplicate entry from table in database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql, jquery-ui

So I have a new requirement that is tricky to me and I'm unable to figure out so far. I am using a gridview to insert, and update data. One of the requirements that I have is when a user manually adds a new record, if the same "deal number" exists then display a pop up. This pop up should show the record that already exists. They should be able to click 1 of 3 buttons which are "use", "discard", or "Ok". The "use" button will basically close the pop up and clear the textboxes the user was entering in. The "discard" button must delete the record that exists so the user can insert the new record using that same deal number. The reason for this is because the deal number is the most unique number for the "deals" that occur. With the way we are exporting from an old application to a new one, duplicates are downloaded, sometimes some with more information than the first time it was exported. This is why I must add a requirement for the user to choose which record for them to keep. I hope this makes sense to you all. I have dried a few things, but this is what I currently have and I'm stuck on.

The Jquery Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function showpopup() {
            $("#popup").dialog("open");
        }

        $("#popup").dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 450,
            autoOpen: false,
            open: function (type, data) {
                $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
            }
        });

        $("#popup").each(function () {
            var popup = $(this);
            popup.parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

And now the division the script calls which has another gridview to display the existing record..

```
<div class="popUpStyle" title="Duplicate Deal Found!" id="popup" style="display:none">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvDealTracking" runat="server" Width="200px" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Stock #">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDupStockNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StockNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Deal #">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDupDealNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FIMAST") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DealDate">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDupDealDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DealDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Buyer">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDupBuyer" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Buyer") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GrossProfit">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDupGrossProfit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GrossProfit") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AmtFinanced">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDupAmtFinanced" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AmtFinanced") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BankName">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblDupBankName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BankName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnUse" Text="Use" runat="server"></asp:Button>
            <asp:Button ID="btnDiscard" Text="Discard" runat="server" OnClick="btnDiscard_Click" style="display:none"></asp:Button>
            <asp:Label ID="lblMessagePop" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <br />
        </div>
```

And now the code behind that I use to try to delete the existing record..

```
 protected void btnDiscard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
                string dealnumber = ((Label)gvr.FindControl("lblDupDealNumber")).Text.Trim();

                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmdDeleteDup = new SqlCommand("DELETE * FROM Vehicle WHERE FIMAST = @FIMAST", conn);
                cmdDeleteDup.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIMAST", dealnumber);
                cmdDeleteDup.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblMessagePop.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

The button click isn't not firing and I do now know how to make it work. I tried a few different things but same results. I'm using a reader that checks to see if the record does exists and I show this pop up if it does have rows. It displays perfectly, just my buttons don't do anything. If this isn't the proper way to go about this, please let me know. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

This is how I'm calling the popup in c#. This has reader that checks to see if the rows exist, and if so, it displays the existing record in the popup. I use a data adapter to do this. Then I use Page.ClientScript... to open the popup and display the results.

```
SqlDataReader rdr = null;
                SqlCommand cmdCheckExisting = new SqlCommand("SELECT StockNumber, DealDate, Buyer FROM Vehicle WHERE FIMAST = '" + DealNumber + "';", conn);
                rdr = cmdCheckExisting.ExecuteReader();
                if (rdr.HasRows)
                {
                    rdr.Close();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SqlDataAdapter cmdReturnExisting = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT StockNumber, FIMAST, DealDate, Buyer, GrossProfit, AmtFinanced, BankName FROM Vehicle WHERE FIMAST = '" + DealNumber + "';", conn);
                    cmdReturnExisting.Fill(dt);
                    gvDealTracking.DataSource = dt;
                    gvDealTracking.DataBind();

                    conn.Close();

                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function", "showpopup();", true);
                }
```

Comment: Are you trying to trigger the click method of that button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I simply changed the buttons to LinkButtons. For some reason, everything works perfectly if asp linkbutton is placed outside or inside the gridview. Here is the popup with the gridview.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                function showpopup() {
                    $("#popup").dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        width: 590,
                        buttons: {
                            Ok: function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                };
            </script>

             <div class="popUpStyle" title="Duplicate Deal Found!" id="popup" style="display:none">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvDealTracking" runat="server" Width="200px" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Stock #" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDupStockNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StockNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dealership" SortExpression="Dealership">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Dealership") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Dealership") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Deal #" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDupDealNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FIMAST") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <HeaderStyle Wrap="False" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DealDate">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDupDealDate" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DealDate","{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Buyer">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDupBuyer" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Buyer") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="GrossProfit">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDupGrossProfit" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GrossProfit","{0:n2}") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="AmtFinanced">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDupAmtFinanced" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AmtFinanced","{0:C}") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="BankName">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDupBankName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BankName") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <br />
                 <asp:Button ID="btnUse" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnUse_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Use"></asp:Button>
<asp:Button ID="lbDelete" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="lbDelete_Click" Text="Delete"></asp:Button>
                 <asp:Label ID="lblMessagePop" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <br />
            </div>
```

EDIT: Thanks to Chad, he pointed out that asp buttons default to use the submit behavior. Setting the UseSubmitBehavior option to false within the button solves the issue. You are now able to use asp buttons within the popup to call your c# methods.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Try removing "style='display:none'" from your div and add "autoOpen: false" into the dialog. Then the only thing your "showpopup()" function needs to do is call "$("#popup").dialog('open');"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#popup").dialog({
        modal: true,
        width: 450,
        autoOpen: false,
        open: function(type,data) {
            $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
        }
    });

    $("#popup").each(function() { 
        var popup = $(this); 
        popup.parent().appendTo($("form:first")); 
    });

    function showpopup() {
        $("#popup").dialog("open");
    }
 });
```

Comment: I gave this a shot. I removed the jQuery buttons, but now it just seems to freeze. I'm unable to click on any of the buttons or even more the popup around. I do have an "x" at the top right hand corner and I'm unable to click on that as well. What could be the problem? On my other attempts at this, I had the same problem, so I'm not completely positive. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Even without the.. $("#popup").each(function() { 
        var popup = $(this); 
        popup.parent().appendTo($("form:first")); 
    }); the buttons appear in the form, I'm able to click on them, and move the popup around like normal, but my buttons don't fire. This is about the 3rd attempt that I have used the "form:first" and each time it seems to "lock" the page. It's strange to me.

Comment: Try my edit that includes `open: function(type,data) {
    $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
  }`

Comment: Tried the edits as well, still the same issue. It just "locks" up still. Unable to click on any of the buttons, the exit button. This one is puzzling me.

Comment: Last idea, I edited my answer. If that doesn't work then I'm not sure what you have going on.

Comment: I gave those edits a shot as well, this time it just doesn't open the popup. I also have no idea what is going on with this. I don't use jQuery too often. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you sure that you have your JQuery inside of the `$(document).ready(function() {....});` and that you are calling your `showpopup()` correctly?

Comment: I have edited my question with the newest script that you have helped me with and how I'm calling the popup in the behind code.

Comment: It still doesn't look like you wrapped your javascript in `$(document).ready(function() {...code goes here...});`. If that isn't you problem I'm stumped because everything else looks correct.

Comment: I have edited my question again and updated the script. I think this is what you meant? I have given it a shot and received an error of..Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'showpopup' is undefined but I'm not sure if I wrapped it correctly? On the few popups that I have used I haven't used the $(document) before.

Comment: I'm not sure sir, I have tried your suggested edit and received  "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'showpopup' is undefined." I may have to just rethink this all together and find a different solution. Maybe the deleting from a popup was a poorly constructed idea. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: Not a problem, and I don't think it is too bad of an idea honestly. It seems that now your problem is that your C# function is firing before your javascript gets loaded. However, I'm not sure how to resolve that.

Comment: I have found an solution. It makes no sense to me really. I was wondering if you had any insights why it would work? I have answered my own question if you would like to take a look.

Comment: Looking through this: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article99.aspx I see that an `<asp:Button>` defaults to a submit button unless you set `UserSubmitBehavior=false`. I was unaware of this before, but seeing that since a LinkButton does not have the submit behavior that might be the difference. If so, then using a normal `<asp:Button UserSubmitBehavior="False"` should work as well.

Comment: well, that was the single thing I did not look up. Thanks again for your help sir. I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, I actually learned something here, too. I was unaware of the asp button defaulting to a submit button, unless specified as false. Glad to hear you have things working!